# Binding colors of shapes with variables c#

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, colors

How I can bind colour of rectangle and my bool **in c# code** if i arledy have converter? I dont have rectange in xaml, I just creating it in code and adding on grid.

Comment: I want to change color of rectange in depedning on the value of boolean variable. I alredy have converter wich convert this boolean variable to color, but i dont know how to bind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511484/wpf-rectangle-color-binding)

To add a binding in code:

```
    Binding binding = new Binding("State");
    binding.Converter = new BooleanToBrushConverter();
    _rectangle.SetBinding(Rectangle.FillProperty, binding);
```