# C# Setting a field from a string

Tags: c#, wpf

I am building a UWF program and I want to make it so every x seconds 3 random squares change color.

There are around 40 squares in total and each of them are named rec1 - rec42. So my thinking was to randomly pick a square by combining two strings, "rec" and a random int. But now I have to set a field from a string is that even possible? Am I even understanding/approaching this right?

This is my current method

```
void animatedGraphics_Tick(object sender, object e) {
        //List of color
        String[] possibleColor = { "#FF443806", "#FF332E04", "#FF130F03" };

        Random rnd = new Random();
        //Loop for three square
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            //generate pick squares to change
            string square = ("rec" + rnd.Next(1, 43));

            //Something like square.fill = possibleColor[rnd.Next(0,3)];
        }
    }
```

Thanks

**edit**: This is what I ended up using

```
        void animatedGraphics_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        //List of color converted to from ARGB values
        Color[] possibleColor = { Color.FromArgb(255, 65, 54 ,9), 
            Color.FromArgb(255, 19, 15, 3), Color.FromArgb(255, 51, 46, 3) };

        Random rnd = new Random();
        //Loop for three square
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            //Use FindName to locate the shape 
            Rectangle square = (Rectangle) this.FindName("rec" + rnd.Next(1,42));

            //Change the shape color
            square.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(possibleColor[rnd.Next(0,3)]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the exact type of the squares?

Comment: XAML rectangles class ===>                                                                                            <Rectangle x:Name="rec1" Height="16" Width="39" Fill="#FF413609" Margin="2"/>

Comment: Have you looked at this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511484/wpf-rectangle-color-binding

Comment: I would recommend to put your squares in a list or array of some kind and than acces a random index rather than the object by name this will make your code better servicable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not the best way to do it but you can get the control by his name calling this.FindName()
Then the Fill method takes a Brush as a parameter, you can use the SolidBrushColor.
Finally to convert from hexa to a Color you can use ColorConverter.ConvertFromString()

```
Color color = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(possibleColor[rnd.Next(0,3)]);  
SolidColorBrush myBrush = new SolidColorBrush(color);  
Rectangle myRectangle = (Rectangle) this.FindName(square);  
myRectangle.Fill(myBrush);
```